# How can I emulate moving water in the BGE?

Tags: game-engine

I am not sure how to make a texture of water make waves and stuff.  I know how to do it in Render, but not BGE (Blender Game Engine). Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How about an animated texture? If you rendered out the waves in Blender Internal, then loaded them into the BGE, you would have animated water.

Comment: I am not exactly sure what you mean.

Comment: @BlenderLover It's not quite moving water, exactly, but you might find this interesting.. [Water Shader](http://www.blendernation.com/2013/06/22/waterunderwater-sky-shader/) and  [pre-made BGE shaders](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.4/Tutorials/Game_Engine/Resources/Shaders)

Comment: There is also deformation scripts I use that actually make real and animated waves in the game engine, I'll post back here with a proper .blend file within the week.

Comment: have you looked into normal maps at all? you will need one of those and then you can animate a plane by changing the position of the texture. there are tens of videos on doing this.

Answer (score 3):

The only way that works well and looks great in the BGE, is creating an animated water texture.

Having real geometry to create displaced waves in the game engine would look cool, but it is very memory intensive and would cause your game to lag.

To create an animated texture for the water, there are quite a few steps. [Here is a video that describes the technique used to create the water used in the Blender Game "Yo! Frankie"](http://www.yofrankie.org/tutorial-animated-normal-maps/).

Video Summary:
Step by step tutorial that shows how to create realtime animated water for the BGE using animation maps.

Answer (score 0):

On a side note you can also emulate moving water directly from vertices, here's an example; I do however strongly recommend cleaning it up a bit.

[.BLEND FILE](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/387475783838466051/603392268396789761/WATERSTACKOVERFLOW.blend)

This is however not animating water directly to a plain, and shouldn't be done on a larger scale as it will drag down performance.